# Displaying JFrame

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe

I'm having issues figuring out how to open one window when another closes if the other window is initiated within a sub class. Here is the clumsy code I am trying to use, but it halts the setting visible of the sub classe's window. Perhaps due to it being within an action event or perhaps it is halting the main thread.

```
    tutorial = new tutorialWindow();
    this.setVisible(false);
    tutorial.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    tutorial.setVisible(true);
    tutorial.setCurrentUser(users.getCurrentUser());

    while(tutorial.isOpen() == true ) {
    }
    this.setVisible(true);
    users.updateUser(tutorial.getCurrentUser());
```

My thoughts were that it would just get stuck in the section of code until the other window closes and would then appear again when the tutorialWindow has a Open boolean set to false due to it breaking the while loop.

Im sure this is a matter of using correct threads, or perhaps the various notify methods but as of now I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: 1) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), 2) don't multiplay windows use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: I am using null layout for various reasons.

Comment: @LiamB : Absolute Positioning is hardly needed in any situation. In order for someone to post a good answer to your query post one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @nIcE cOw: Will do, it's just hardly worth writing even a small class to ask for an alternative to using a while loop for managing JFrames. Absolute position is needed for this project, using a lot of animation and overlayed jLabels that don't format without null layout in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: @LiamB : But using `while(true)` loops inside your GUI, might can halt your EDT- Event Dispatch Thread. Seems like the answer by Francisco is the way to go then :-) +1 to that answer

Comment: Yes I am still stuck though, it is mostly due to bad class organisation I guess, but too far in to rectify (eeek), have a look at the comments of that answer please, maybe you have a solution. Thanks :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html). In the following sample [`WindowAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) implements `WindowListener` and I just override the `public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent e)` method, opening the second window.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TestJFrame {

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        JFrame jFrame1 = new JFrame();
        jFrame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame1.add(new JLabel("First JFrame"));
        jFrame1.pack();

        final JFrame jFrame2 = new JFrame();
        jFrame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame2.add(new JLabel("Second JFrame"));
        jFrame2.pack();

        jFrame1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(final WindowEvent e) {
                jFrame2.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        jFrame1.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think this will work, problem is I have custom close buttons made from jLabels that run this.dispose(); How do i integrate it now?

Comment: Ohh sorry, it was my fault: I implements `windowClosing` but the right is `windowClosed`, just change it and you'll see it will work.

Comment: Hmmm, this won't work now that I think about it. It would work if both JFrames were declared within the same class, but since the JFrame that I am closing is declared within a class that is declared in the Main JFrame I cannot refer to the set visible of the Main JFrame from the Tutorial window (declared lower down in class heirachy).

Comment: I think for now I will make it so the main frame does not close, but will hide in background, so I don't need to re-open it, it will solve the problem. But I would still like to know how to get around this issue correctly.